# Cannot execute Android projects after updating android studio to 4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.0, android-studio-4.1

I have updated my android studio from 3.5 to 4.1 and after updating I am facing this error to my already existing projects.

```
Could not open cp_init remapped class cache for 679impwcp2nsmss9dbzs5238f (C:\Users\aj\.gradle\caches\5.4.1\scripts-remapped\sync_studio_tooling1_5z6x0ktwhukyodh1964emspbz\679impwcp2nsmss9dbzs5238f\cp_initdcd040730888da95d185715568c9cc57).
> Could not open cp_init generic class cache for initialization script 'C:\Users\aj\AppData\Local\Temp\sync.studio.tooling1.gradle' (C:\Users\aj\.gradle\caches\5.4.1\scripts\679impwcp2nsmss9dbzs5238f\cp_init\cp_initdcd040730888da95d185715568c9cc57).
   > Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.Verifier
```

Could anyone guide me solving this issue ?

Comment: you tried going back to android 4.0?

Comment: no i did not try that, i updated to the latest.

Comment: might be worth going back to 4.0 until the bugs in 4.1 has been fixed

Comment: @SimonSzarko thanks. i think 4.1 version is stable which i have downloaded.